# Excel How to make a formula differenciate different vehicle plates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have little knowlage of excel and I'm trying to configure an excel table so I can get the consumption of gas for each vehicle in a company, but all the data is introduced in only one table, how can I calculate the increase of km's of each vehicle to then be able to calculate the consumption?

The problem is that I don't know how to make the formula differenciate for each different plate.

The table is the following:

```
        **A         B             C      D    E           F            G**
**1**    Date       Plate       km      Gas Signed  Increased km's  Consum
**2**    1/1/2018   0157-AAA    123456  50  YES     
**3**    5/1/2018   0157-AAA    123789  20  NO      
**4**    8/2/2018   0157-AAA    123987  30  NO      
**5**    1/2/2018   0582-BBB    123456  40  YES     
**6**    1/3/2018   0356-CCC    123456  30  NO
```

Another exemple:

```
 Data        Plate      km    Gas   Increased km    Consum %
3/5/2017    1111-AAA    150    20      150          13,33333333
7/5/2017    1111-AAA    400    30      250          12
7/5/2017    2222-BBB    50     10       50          20
7/5/2017    3333-CCC    20      5       20         25
10/5/2017   2222-BBB    200    30      150         20
```

Each plate is a different vehicle

Gas is the amount of oil that the vehicle refills in L

The table is updated daily or every 2-3 days as it's manually filled

The problem is calculating the increased km's as they may be other plates in between in the same date.

Consum % =  Gas/Increased km *100

I thought about just ordering the columns by date and by plate and apply a general formula to everything

Thanks

Comment: That depends. .. donyou want to report the overall consumption by vegucle for each period reported (ie., 0157-AAA for 5/1 and 8/2)? Or overall by vehicle? Overall by company?

Comment: What would you expect for the first entry, since you don't have a previous value for that plate?

Comment: They want to get the data of AVG oil consumption of the company per month, per vehicle each time he refills the oil, and the total of oil conusmed each month + the total of km's each month

Comment: the plates are defined by a list which limits the values

Comment: so for each line item, you want the difference between that km reading and the last km reading of that plate?

Comment: You can start with `=$C2-IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C, MAX(IF($B$1:$B1=$B2, ROW($B$1:$B1), -1))), 0)` and see where that gets you. That leaves the 1st occurence of each plate unchanged

Comment: The formula has an error when i paste it in Increased km's :$

Comment: This is straightforward but I have some questions to clarify what you need: `each time he refills the oil, and the total of oil consumed each month`  You're calculating _oil_ consumption??  I'll assume that's a typo.  The the figure for `Gas` in Litres?  Also, with your sample data, **only one vehicle** will report consumption.  Consumption (km/L) can't be calculated without at least a start and and end figure.  Also, I assume the file will contain more data than your example?  Will the file be updated regularly, or will you receive new files that need to be added?

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally "solved my problem", the formula with the one I work is based on  a filter for the plates in order to get them ordered. then the formula is:

Increased km =IF(B2=B1;C2-C1;C2)

Comment: Yes this is easiest if the plates are ordered - just subtract from previous row if the plates match. I'd say delete the question as it doesn't really have value in the archives IMO